# Cropped video changes to original uncropped version when saved as a media file

Tags: crop, microsoft-powerpoint, video

I used Powerpoint to create a screen recording and cropped the recording in Powerpoint, but when I saved it as an mp4 media file the entire part of the screen that was originally recorded, instead of the cropped part, is shown. Does anyone have suggestions regarding how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have to use PowerPoint to crop the video? Can you use any other video editing software to crop the video? The cropped feature might only work while the video is in PowerPoint or viewing as a PowerPoint file.

Comment: What software can be used to crop an mp4 video? I tried to crop the video, but there was no option to crop it

Comment: there are a lot of video editings apps out there. You could try the free version of Adobe Premiere Rush or the default video editing software on Windows (Photos app) and Mac (iMovie, QuickTime) to name a few. What do you mean you tried to crop the video?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try one of those apps. I meant that I tried to see if there was a way to crop the video.